# K-Nearest-Neighbors: Plotting the decision boundary with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, plot, classification, knn

I am currently working on implementing the k-NN classifier.

I got a JavaFX application which plots some points in a linechart. Plotting decision boundaries of linear classifiers like a perceptron works fine, since it's just a straight line.

I'm wondering if it's possible to plot the decision boundary of a k-NN classifier in JavaFX. What i'd like to achieve is something like this: 
[image: Example]

Is this possible using the available JavaFX components?

Comment: The problem with using `XYCharts` is that those lines/areas are not bounded by (mathematical) functions. Of course it is possible to achieve this kind of output using existing components...

Comment: Is the information about K-NN relevant here ? If you can figure out the coordinates of each point on the boundary you should be able to plot it.

Comment: Probably not too relevant indeed. I might be able to figure out the coordinates of the boundary points, i'm not sure though, how to color the area underneath those boundaries. Are the any examples using CSS or something?